# Authorization error Terraform Databricks provider

Tags: authentication, terraform, databricks, terraform-provider-databricks, databricks-unity-catalog

I got the authorization error when tried to create a catalog: "Cannot create catalog: User not authorized".
This is the definition of Terraform Databricks provider for workspace:

`provider "databricks" { host = module.databricks.dbx_workspace_url auth_type = "azure-cli" }`

When I omit `auth_type = "azure-cli"` and leave just host, the result is the same.

Any opinion on this?

I've tried to use the Databricks token after creating Workspace, but in my solution, Workspace and Unity Catalog should be created in the same apply.

Comment: Are you certain your user has permission to CREATE CATALOG on the Metastore you have assigned to the workspace? The error seems like you have passed authentication and are instead failing authorization.

Comment: It should since with the same user are created the metastore and the dbx workspace.